# How do I resize an array in Scala

Tags: database, arrays, scala, resize

I am trying to create a DB management tool in Scala, and I want to be able to draw from this database into Arrays, whose size can shift based on the data being passed to them. I know how to do this in C, PHP, VB, etc. but can't seem to figure out the syntax for Scala.

I'm sure this should be a simple problem, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hah! Much thanks to Brian Angew for pointing me to ArrayBuffers which are explained very well in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527131/scala-dynamic-multi-dimensional-mutable-arrays-like-datastructures).  Got what I need now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collections by default in Scala tend to be immutable. Operations will create new immutable collections from existing collections (by adding/removing elements etc.). The benefit of this is that collections don't change under iteration and writing multi-threaded applications *tends* to be easier (lots of caveats/assumptions with how you write standard Java apply here!).

Having said all that, if you need a mutable array, have you looked at an [ArrayBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html) (a mutable collection with an underlying array implementation) ?

e.g.

```
val a = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
a += "A"
a += "B"
a(1)   // gives you 'B'
```

Comment: So, is there a way of adding and removing objects from a normal array thereby creating a new array?   Also, ResizeableArray sounds like what I want, but I'm not sure how to instantiate one because "val info:ResizeableArray[String]=new ResizeableArray[String](3)" isn't working

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bare beginner at Scala, and am having trouble finding functional code examples for what I am trying to do

Comment: Sorry. Mislead you with the ResizableArray. That's a trait on top of ArrayBuffer. Check out the above for an example of modifying an array

Comment: No Problem!  Now, if I were to try to add a 2nd row to that Array, would I do that by making a second array, and appending them somehow, or is there an easier way with this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [System.copy](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-system-class-to-copy-array.html) for this task, if you really want to use an array, or you could directly use a container that will resize itself automatically, such as [ListBuffer](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html) or [ArrayList.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)